# Show that $f \in H^{\frac{1}{2}}$, using that $\iint_{\mathbb{T}^1\times \mathbb{T}^1} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{sin^2(\pi(x-y))} \,dx\,dy < \infty$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I am trying to solve an exercise from the book: "Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis" from *Muscalu* and *Schlag*, but I am stuck on the following problem:

Given a function $f \in C^0(\mathbb{T}^1)$ that satisfies the following property: $$ \iint_{\mathbb{T}^1\times \mathbb{T}^1} \frac{\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert^2}{\sin^2(\pi(x-y))} \,dx\,dy < \infty $$

Then $ f \in H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{T}^1)$.

I know that $\|f\|_{H^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \lvert\hat f(0)\rvert^2 + \sum_{n \neq 0} \lvert n\rvert\lvert\hat f(n)\rvert^2$. I was trying to bound the $n^{th}$ Fourier coefficient  of $f$, but I did not manage to make any progress. I would like $\sum_{n \neq 0} \lvert n\rvert\lvert \hat f(n)\rvert^2$ to be convergent but I don't see how.

What I was able to show:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lvert\hat f(n)\rvert^2 &=& \left|\int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2 \pi i n x} \,dx \right|^2 \\
&\leq& \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert^2 \,dx \; (\textrm{using the fact that $\int_0^1 e^{-2\pi inx}dx = 0$) } \\
&\leq& \iint_{\mathbb{T}^1\times \mathbb{T}^1} \frac{\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert^2}{\sin^2(\pi(x-y))} \,dx\,dy \\
&<& \infty
\end{eqnarray}

Can someone help me? I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Here I give a proof of a stronger, rather marvelous fact, which of course implies your result.
$$\int_{\mathbb{T}} |f(x+t) - f(x)|^2 = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f}(k) - e(kt)\hat{f}(k)|^2 =\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f}(k)|^2\left( (1-\cos(2\pi kt)^2) + \sin^2(2\pi kt)\right)$$
$$=2\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f}(k)|^2(1-\cos(2\pi k t)) = 4\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(k)|^2 \sin^2(\pi k t).$$
Whence we see
$$\int_{\mathbb{T}}\int_{\mathbb{T}} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|^2}{\sin^2(\pi (x-y))} \ dx \ dy = \int_\mathbb{T}\int_\mathbb{T} \frac{|f(x+t) - f(x)|^2}{\sin^2(\pi t)} \ dx \ dt$$
$$= 4\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(k)|^2 \int_\mathbb{T}\frac{\sin^2(\pi k t)}{\sin^2(\pi t)} \ dt= 4\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |k||\hat{f}(k)|^2 \int_\mathbb{T} K_{|k|}(t) \ dt$$
$$=4\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |k||\hat{f}(k)|^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 t}{t^2}=1$ you can find $\delta>0$ such that $$\frac12\le \frac{\sin^2 t}{t^2}\le\frac32$$ for all $0<|t|\le\delta$. In turn
$$\int\int_{\{|\pi (x-y)|\le\delta\}} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{|x-y|^2}dxdy\le 2 \int\int_{\{|\pi (x-y)|\le\delta\}} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{\sin^2(\pi(x-y))}dxdy.$$ On the other hand, 
$$\int\int_{\{|\pi (x-y)|>\delta\}} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{|x-y|^2}dxdy\le \frac1{\delta^2}\int\int_{\{|\pi (x-y)|>\delta\}} |f(x)-f(y)|^2dxdy<\infty.$$
Thus, 
$$\int_{\mathbb{T}^1}\int_{\mathbb{T}^1} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{|x-y|^2}dxdy\le \frac1{\delta^2}\int\int_{\{|\pi (x-y)|>\delta\}} |f(x)-f(y)|^2dxdy<\infty.$$
This is an equivalent seminorm in $H^{1/2}$.